# Hover pseudo-element on parent class with scss

Tags: css, sass

How would I translate the following CSS into SCSS?

```
.parent-class:hover .child-class {
  visibility: visible;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 450ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

The following code does not seem to work:

```
.parent-class{
  &:hover .childclass{
    visibility: visible;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 450ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition-delay:0s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scss has the right idea - except that you have a typo in your class name:

`.childclass` -> `.child-class`

```
.parent-class{
  &:hover .child-class{
    visibility: visible;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 450ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition-delay:0s;
  }
}
```

Comment: whoops... Sorry for that! I was going crazy searching for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Danield is right, just to make it more concise:

```
.parent-class {
  &:hover .child-class {
    visibility: visible;
    animation: bounceIn 450ms linear forwards;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
}
```